# How can I set the id if we combined the classes in spring MVC?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc

I have 2 classes: `Employee` and `DailyReport` and I call both in another class like this:

```
public class Bean {

    private Employee employees;
    private DailyReport dailyReports;

    //getters and setters
```

and the controller for edit is:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/editEmployee", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String getEdit(@RequestParam(value="emp_id") Integer emp_id,  Model model) {
    Bean bean=new Bean();

    bean.setEmployees(employeeService.getEmployee(emp_id));
    model.addAttribute("bean",bean);
    return "addemployee";
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/editEmployee", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String postEdit(@RequestParam(value="emp_id") Integer emp_id, @ModelAttribute("bean")Bean bean) {
    Employee employee=new Employee();
    employee.setEmp_id(emp_id)//how can I set the emp_id??
    employeeService.edit(employee);
  
    return "search";
}
```

My question is: In post method how can I set the employee id for editing?

Comment: You shouldn't. You should read the employee identified by emp_id from your persistent storage and write changes to that employee. `setEmp_id()` shouldn't even be a method. Also, it should be called `empId` because in java we only use `_` for constants.

Comment: if i'm directly using the employee class ,it is working ..i'm able to edit..bt, when  i'm working with bean class ...it is not working...i don't know what the changes i have to make   here..if i'm not setting the changes , the error message is coming as "id to load is required"

Comment: and it is employee.setEmp_id(emp_id)...not id ...sorry i done the mistake in the question

Comment: I see you have set the employee id , may I know what else you need ? Please try to be specific with your questions.

Answer (score 0):

@Umesh Sanwal :        this is my dao class:

```
        public void edit(Employee employee) {
        Session sessions = session.getCurrentSession();
        Employee existingEmployee = (Employee) sessions.get(Employee.class, 
        employee.getEmp_id());
        existingEmployee.setEmp_id(employee.getEmp_id());
        existingEmployee.setName(employee.getName());
        existingEmployee.setDesignation(employee.getDesignation());
        existingEmployee.setLocation(employee.getLocation());
        existingEmployee.setEmployee_type(employee.getEmployee_type());
        sessions.save(existingEmployee);
         }
```

and service class is:

```
                      @Transactional
                      public void edit(Employee employee) {
                      employeeDao.edit(employee);
```

and the bean class is:

```
                       public class Bean {

                       private Employee employees;
                       private DailyReport dailyReports;
```

my question is how can i set the edit operation in controller??